# Vue recomputing everything on object change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to know when an object property is changed does vue recompute all of the computed related to that object or does it just recompute the ones related to the property changed? If so is there a way to make it recompute only the ones related? (I am having performance issues and I am guessing it is because of this)

Example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#logs',
  data: {
    test: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
    }
  },
  computed: {   
    aTimesTen: function() {
      return this.test.a * 10;
    },
    bTimesEleven: function() {
      return this.test.b * 11;
    },
  },
});
```

If I update test.a will bTimesEleven be recomputed?

Comment: Can you just try it? But yes...

Comment: you could use "real" setter/getters instead of the bolted-on computed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, `bTimesEleven` should not be recalculated when `this.test.a` changes because it only depends on `this.test.b`

As said in the docs:

> computed properties are cached based on their dependencies.